# How to change wireless network properties on Windows 8?

Tags: networking, windows-8

When I click the network icon in the system tray and then right click on a wireless network on the "charm bar" or whatever it's called when it appears and the select "View Connection Properties" I get the "Wireless Network Properties" window where everything is disabled. There is also a box in that window saying "These settings are managed by your system administrator". Needless to say that I am an administrator.

I suspect that this can be configured via Policy Editor, but I can't find the right setting. I had a similar problem being unable to bridge network adapters which I successfully solved by changing a value in the Policy Editor.

Does anyone know how to make these properties changeable?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a work computer it's probably policy enforced by the network admins and you should probably approach them for assistance.

Regardless of that, it's most likely caused by a policy setting in `Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Network List Manager Policies`.

You can use `rsop.msc` to determine which GP settings are currently applied to your computer/user.

Comment: Thanks, rsop.msc really helped, finding out that for this particular network setting are really configured on the domain level. It was not the case with the "allow network bridge" settings.